# 2d vector input and display through function

Tags: c++, vector

I have written this code to input and display a 2d vector matrix but it is not working can someone help me identify the errors.
The main function is only taking input a and b and the function are not called properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> input(int a, int b)
{
    vector<vector<int>> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
void display(vector<vector<int>> arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    vector<vector<int>> arr;
    arr = input(a, b);
    display(arr);
}
```

Comment: Note that `arr` is passed by value to `display()`. To avoid the unnecessary copy, use a const reference instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `input` function the vector `arr` is *empty*. That means `arr.size()` will return `0` and the loops will not happen.

If you know the dimensions of the vectors from the beginning (I assume they are the (pretty badly named) `a` and `b` variables) then you can use that to set the size:

```
vector<vector<int>> input(int a,int b)
{
     // Create a vector of a elements, each element is in turn a vector of b elements
    vector<vector<int>> arr(a, vector<int>(b));
    // ...
}
```

See e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for more information about the constructors used (alternative 2 and 3).